# Why can't I use lambda expressions in the Immediate Window?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [VS debugging “quick watch” tool and lambda expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725499/vs-debugging-quick-watch-tool-and-lambda-expressions)

I'm curious if there is a reason that this is not allowed in the Visual Studio immediate window while debugging?

Comment: I would not surprised if this changes in one of the next versions of VS. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/10/19/the-roslyn-preview-is-now-available.aspx

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409072/visual-studio-immediate-window-lambda-expressions-arent-allowed-is-there-a

Comment: Appearantly this is supported in VS2015: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2014/11/12/support-for-debugging-lambda-expressions-with-visual-studio-2015.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Jaredpar explained it

[Why is LINQ absent from debugger windows?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/08/26/why-no-linq-in-debugger-windows.aspx)

[Why is LINQ absent from debugger windows (Part 2)?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2010/06/02/why-is-linq-absent-from-debugger-windows-part-2.aspx)

Comment: Links are broken. Answers should be more than just links to external sites to avoid situations like that.